# SEO for multilingual site

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have this site and I want to rewrite URL's:

> mydomain.com/referinte?lang=en
>
> mydomain.com/referinte?lang=ro

Is there a possibility so I can use .htaccess to modify the url like this:

> mydomain.com/en/references
>
> mydomain.com/ro/referinte

My current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: To clarify, you would like to have URLs like `mydomain.com/en/references` which are rewritten to `mydomain.com/references.php?lang=en`?

Comment: I would like to have URLs like mydomain.com/en/references and now the URLs look like this: mydomain.com/references.php?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your input, I would suggest using URL rewriting configuration as follows:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z-_]+)$  $1.php?lang=en  [R]
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z-_]+)$  $2.php?lang=$1  [R]
```

The first rule rewrites URLs like `/abc` (with no specified language) to `/abc.php?lang=en` and sets English (`en`) as a default language
The second rule rewrites URLs like `/xy/abc` (with specified language) to `/abc.php?lang=xy` (language is taken from the first *part* of the request URL)

Examples:

- `http://mydomain.com/en/references => http://mydomain.com/references.php?lang=en` (RewriteRule #2)
- `http://mydomain.com/ro/referinte => http://mydomain.com/referinte.php?lang=ro` (RewriteRule #2)
- `http://mydomain.com/references => http://mydomain.com/references.php?lang=en` (RewriteRule #1)
- `http://mydomain.com/referinte => http://mydomain.com/referinte.php?lang=en` (RewriteRule #1)

Please note that the rules will ignore requests for specific `PHP` files i.e. requests as follows: `http://mydomain.com/ro/referinte.php` or `http://mydomain.com/referinte.php` will not be rewritten. Also, server response should be the same for non-existing pages as currently i.e. assuming `/referinte.php` does not exist, the requests as follows:  `http://mydomain.com/en/referinte` (new rewriting) and  `http://mydomain.com/referinte?lang=en` (current rewriting) I presume would return 404.

I hope that will help.